# QML Singleton Parse error

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML singleton file which I use it for saving user variables to be used in the application.
I use the same file for storing variables like `#define` in C++.
The issue is if I add new parameters and compile and run the app, the values that I read from the old variables from the singleton file reads junk values until I add a `console.log()`. 
This happens every single time I add new variables to the file.

Is this a known bug? I am using Qt 5.8 on a Yocto build.

**Edit:** Added a minimal project files to reproduce the error. I tried this in Ubuntu 16 as well.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Scene
    {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

**Style.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject
{
    property color green: "#558B2F"
    property color red: "#DD2C00"
    property color black: "black"

    property int dialogPopupDuaration: 100
    property int dialogTimeoutValue : 1500
    property int splashTimeout: 5000
    property int rotation: 180

    //Dialog Types
    property int dialogInfo: 0
    property int dialogProcessing: 1
    property int dialogSuccess: 2
    property int dialogFailure: 3

    //Settings
    property int manualOffset: 0
    property int calibrationTimeout: 1
    property bool isUnitMM: true
    property bool isBrightnessHigh: false
    property bool isDMPInit: false
    property int batteryThreshold: 33
    property int batterWarningOffset: 3

    //Uncomment the below lines and run
    //the app will no longer print the qW
    //until i console.log() in main.qml

//            readonly property int boneS: 1
//            readonly property int boneN: 0
//            property int boneType: boneS

//            property int boneTN: boneN
//            property int boneTP: boneN

    //Default quaternion values for the 3D obj
    //to face towards the screen
    property real qX: 0.0
    property real qY: -1.0
    property real qZ: 0.0
    property real qW: -0.5

    property real tolerance: 0.02

    //IMU requires 30s from boot to settle down
    //so if user tries to calibrate it before that
    //use this bool to show warning
    property bool isThirtySecElapsed: false

    readonly property string appVersion: "v1.0.2"
}
```

**Scene.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "."

Rectangle
{
    id: scene
    anchors.fill: parent
    width: parent.width * 0.5
    height: width
    color: "grey"
    Text
    {
        text: Style.qW
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.bold: true
        font.pointSize: 20
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        color: "white"
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        //console.log(Style.qW)
    }
}
```

**qmldir**

```
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Without code it will be hard to answer.

Comment: Have you tested the code on other platforms (Windows/Linux)?

Comment: I have added the code. I am testing this in my Yocto build of linux. I haven't tested it anywhere else yet.

Comment: the code that you sample is not a [mcve], for example as you verify that the data is junk, you have to place in code where it is easy to observe the error.

Comment: @eyllanesc added the required files for testing.

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Did my solution work?

Comment: @eyllanesc No. Adding the module Component didn't change anything. But in the qmldir Qt page they have also used import Component 1.0 instead of ".". I did the same, but it threw an error saying module Component not installed.

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Have you tried my test project? Maybe I made another change and I have not realized, the project works correctly for me.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did not use yours. I just added the module part in my project and checked. And your link as no download option for the project or I missed it?!

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for sharing that. I tried and the issue is there :(

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey I have tested it with Qt 5.10.1 in Linux, try the code on a desktop, maybe the problem is in your installation.

Comment: @eyllanesc I am testing in Ubuntu 16 desktop only running Qt 5.8

Comment: @eyllanesc what's the module Component do here?

Comment: in the qmldir the first line should be: `module Component`

Comment: In the previous code I shared it with a typographical error, download the updated code from this link: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/e43e83814504f1d3480f8b3a789a9c26/archive/81c683d91606423c7f7472a286b6075af59e6138.zip

Comment: @eyllanesc still the same :(

Comment: Well, it's probably a bug, report it and/or update your Qt, good luck.